# curl_easy_perform crashes when the URL is not correct

Tags: c++, multithreading, curl, libcurl

I have a problem trying to download files using `libcurl`. The program works with multiple threads, every thread that needs to download a file creates a `libcurl` handle to work with.

When the URL is correct everything works, but if there is a mistake in the URL the program crashes. In debug mode, if the URL is not correct `curl_easy_perform` returns an error connection code and the program works. In contrast, it crashes in release.

How could I fix this error?

Here is the code that I use to download the file, irrelevant code has been supressed:

```
LoadFileFromServer
(
    string& a_sURL
)
{
    string  sErrorBuffer;

    struct DownloadedFile updateFile = { sFilenameToWrite,  // name to store the local file if succesful
                                         NULL };            // temp buffer

    CURL*   pCurl = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt( pCurl, CURLOPT_URL, a_sURL.data() );
    curl_easy_setopt( pCurl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L );
    curl_easy_setopt( pCurl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, sErrorBuffer );
    curl_easy_setopt( pCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, BufferToFile );
    curl_easy_setopt( pCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &updateFile );
    curl_easy_setopt( pCurl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0 );
    curl_easy_setopt( pCurl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5L );

    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform( pCurl );

    curl_easy_cleanup( pCurl );
}

int BufferToFile
( 
    void *  a_buffer, 
    size_t  a_nSize, 
    size_t  a_nMemb, 
    void *  a_stream 
)
{
    struct DownloadedFile *out = ( struct DownloadedFile * ) a_stream;
    if( out && !out->stream ) 
    {
        // open file for writing 
        if ( 0 != fopen_s( &( out->stream ), out->filename.c_str(), "wb" ) )
            return -1;
        if( !out->stream )
            return -1; /* failure, can't open file to write */
    }

    return fwrite( a_buffer, a_nSize, a_nMemb, out->stream );
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the erroneous URL?

Comment: How does it crash? Does it seg fault or have you tried seeing if it's throwing an exception? Have you tried running through a debugger?

Comment: How is `LoadFileFromServer` being called? Is this function's parameter, a string reference, shared among the various threads?

Comment: The URL is nos correct because host name is invalid.

Comment: I have tried to introduced a try/catch in the code but it crashes anyway and there is no exception to catch. In debug it works ok, curl_easy_perform returns an error connection code.

Comment: `LoadFileFromServer` is being called from the main thread. Some code has been supressed, the URL is a string created in this function with some string reference parameters shared among different threads.

Comment: The hostname is invalid _how_? Is it a non-existant hostname? Does it contain illegal characters?

Comment: It is a non-existant hostname.

Comment: You've got sURL.data() as the value you pass to CURLOPT_URL. The result of data() is not guaranteed to be null-terminated, so you should use c_str() instead because cURL wants that pointer to point to a null-terminated string. I wouldn't be surprised if this error has something to do with the difference between your release build behavior and your debug build behavior.

Answer (score 0):

libcurl requires that the given URL is a pointer to a valid buffer it can read from. If it isn't, the fault is in your code.

If you pass a proper pointer to a (zero terminated) string, that string can be a correct URL or not, but libcurl should not crash because of it (and to my knowledge it doesn't).

Answer (score -1):

First of all you could check all the return codes from functions that supply them, Just to see if everything has worked as you assume it has.

Second, Curl is C, not C++ it doesnt generate exceptions.

Thirdly if your C program is crashing then ALL the code is relevant, C programs can crash in all sorts of interesting ways and the actual cause can be nothing whatsoever to do with Curl, or it may be.

You are making far too many assumptions.

Michael